# regex find alphanumeric on string

Tags: regex, alphanumeric

I am tring to create a regex pattern for find a alphanumeric on a string.

For example:

multa religação 123556N

I have to remove "multa religação".

Comment: In what scripting/programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
\b[^\d]+\b
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lQ3zY6/3

Answer (score -1):

It depends on which language you are using, but the regex would be [0-9] to match only number.